# React-redux how to update component props when the store is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I thought once the store is updated, all related component props will be updated too, but the prop(view) is not updated. and I don't know how to get the updated data.

Here is my test code,

userReducer.js

```
const initialState = null;
const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_USER: {
            return Object.assign({}, action.user)
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default userReducer;
```

(rootReducer)

```
export default combineReducers({
    user: userReducer,
});
```

userAction.js

```
export function login(email, password) {
    let user = {
        'email': email,
    };

    return {
        type: UPDATE_USER,
        user,
    }
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.state = this.state || store.getState();
        console.log(this.state.user);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <div className="App container">
                        {this.user
                            ? <Link to="/logout">Logout</Link>
                            : <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                        }
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                            <Route render={() => <h2>Page not found.</h2>}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

Login.js

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.user); // output: null
    }

```
postLogin = () => {
    let email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    let password = $('input[name="password"]').val();

    this.props.dispatchLogin(email, password);

    console.log(this.props.user); // output: null

    // this.props.history.push('/');
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>email:</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>password:</th>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.postLogin}>Login<

/button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    dispatchLogin: (email, password) => login(email, password),
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

The props are not updated automatically when the store is changed? If so, how can I get the updated value? After login, I redirect to the root(App.js) page but still, the view is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a repo based on your code that you can clone to see a working example. https://github.com/cflynn07/sohelp-2020-04-27

Your main problem is in your `App` component:

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.state = this.state || store.getState();
        console.log(this.state.user);
    }
```

You should never assign or modify `state` directly from your component, instead use `setState` (if not using react-redux), or `dispatch` (if using react-redux) (Here's a good article on why https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)

Since you're using react-redux, you want to get your state data via the component's `props`. You can use react-redux's `connect()` method to map your state to props (mapStateToProps) -- like you're already doing with your Login component.

Also, instead of calling `this.props.history.push('/')` from within your `postLogin()` method, the idiomatic way to redirect with react-router is to use the `<Redirect` component. I provided an example of that in `src/components/Login.js` from the repo linked above.

```js
class Login extends Component {
  postLogin = () => {
    const email = $('input[name="email"]').val()
    const password = $('input[name="password"]').val()
    this.props.dispatchLogin(email, password)
  };

  render () {
    if (this.props.user) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
        ...
```